# Managing Access to private and public activities

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

I have an application that has `Private activities` that only logged users are allowed to have access, and `Public activities` that everyone could have access on.

I'm wondering what could be the best way to manage the access to `Private` and `Public` activities.

I was thinking about storing the user's login and password in `SharedPreferences`, and verifying them at the Start of every  `Private acitivity` to allow access when login and password exist and deny it if not, but I'm not sure if it's possible or not, or if there a better way to do this.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Be warned that everything stored in SharePreferences is plain text, so any obfuscation is up to you to implement. You could also override `startActivity()` and do your check there. If it passes, call super, otherwise inform the user and ask them to log in.

Comment: the `startActivity()` sounds  useful, why don't you give an example in an answer.

Comment: why dont you make the class final where you are saving datas in sharedprefs . That class will not be parent of any class on making it final .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the users login information via SharedPreferences. But please be sure to encrypt them in some way. If you dont, everyone can copy the shared_preferences.xml from the phone and see the password in cleartext if its rooted.

A good way to manage the login state would be a LoginManager like this:

```
public class LoginManager {

    private static LoginManager singelton;

    private Context context;
    private boolean loggedIn;

    private LoginManager(Context c) {
        this.context = c;
    }


    public static LoginManager getInstance() {
        return singelton;
    }

    public static void create(Context c) {
        singelton = new LoginManager(c);
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return loggedIn;
    }

    public boolean login(String name, String password) {
        // get shared prefs and check for correct username/password
        if(validCredentials)
            loggedIn = true;
        else
            loggedIn = false;
        return loggedIn;

    }

    public void logout() {
        loggedIn = false;
    }

}
```

At your login screen or maybe at in Application.onCreate() you can then call LoginManager.create(Context c), and after that, use LoginManager.getInstance().login(name, password) to let the user login.

To check if the user is logged in from any activity you can call  LoginManager.getInstance().isLoggedIn() and set activity specific settings according to this.
For example to hide some activites, you could check if the user is logged in and hide/show buttons to that activities depending on login status.

Comment: The create method should be void isn't it?